# Field of formal rational function and $K(x_1, \dots, x_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

***Def.***  Let $K\subseteq L$ be a field extension, and let $B$ be a subset of $L$. We denote by $K(B)$ the smallest subfield of $L$ containing both $K$ and $B$.

Now, let $R=K[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over a field $K$, and let $$L=\text{Quot}R=\bigg\{\frac{f}{g}\;:\;f, g\in R, g\ne 0\bigg\}$$ be its quotient field, i.e the field of formal rational functions in $n$ variables over $K$.

This field is usually denoted by $K(x_1\dots, x_n)$, and thus by the same round bracket notation as for the smallest extension field of $K$ containing given elements of a larger field, which can be descrived explicity as the set of all rational functions in these elements with coefficients in $K$.

> **Question** Is this ambiguity just notational or are they actually the same field?

Comment: There is no "ambiguity" here. I assume you are really asking whether $K(\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\})=K(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am asking if the fraction field and the smallest field containing $K$ and $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are the same thing...

Comment: Yes, but you said there was an ambiguity, and I have pointed out that the notation in your "Def" requires a set within the parentheses, not a list of elements of a set. So there is no ambiguity. Clearly the two fields are the same.

Comment: Why are the same? Could you give me example?

Comment: Why $L$ coincides with $k(x_1,\dots, x_n)$?

Comment: You are not understanding. $L$ is as you say usually denoted as $K(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$. The problem is this: is this the same field as $K(B)$ where $B=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$? Note  well: $B\ne x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n$ -that makes no sense; $B=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$.

Comment: right, is it the same field? and if so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me repeat what I said in the comments. There is  no ambiguity here. We have the standard notation for the field of fractions $K(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, and we have a definition of what $K(B)$ means for a **set**.

The question remains whether $K(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=K(\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\})$. The answer is "of course" and here are some of the details.

Let $K$ be a field, $R:=K[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables.

Let $L$ denote the field of fractions of $R$, so that $L=\left\{\frac{f}{g}\mid f,g\in R, g\ne0\right\}$. This field is usually denoted by $K(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

Now let $B$ be the set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$. Then consider the field $K(B)$ defined as the smallest subfield of $L$ containing $K$ and the set $B$.

By definition we have that $K(B)\subseteq L$.

Now let $\frac{f}{g}\in L$. We have that $f,g\in K[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$. We can write $f=\sum_{} a_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n} x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\dots x_n^{i_n}$ where the ceofficients are in $K$ and the sum is finite. Now $K(B)$ by definition contains all the $x_i$ and so (being closed under multiplication) contains all the monomials $x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\dots x_n^{i_n}$. $K(B)$ also by definition contains all the coefficients as these are in $K$. Hence, as $K(B)$ is a field it must contain $f$. The same is true for $g$. But $K(B)$ is a field so it must contain also $\frac{f}{g}$. That is $L\subseteq K(B)$.

We therefore have that $L=K(B)$.

That is, using the usual notation for the field of fractions,
$$
K(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=K(\{x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n\})
$$
and we are done.